# Using Flet with NGINX

Tags: nginx, deployment, progressive-web-apps, reverse-proxy, flet

I tried using Flet with NGINX by following the exact example in the guide, but it didn't work. My page opens with the Flet icon but keeps loading indefinitely. Here is the link to the example: https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/deploying-web-app/hosting-providers/self-hosting/.

Can someone please fix the guide?

flet Version: 0.20.2

Bring the guide up to date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.